# Deleted plugins still in database? (and reappearing in project.yaml)

Tags: craft3, plugins, database

I can see about 10 plugins in the `craft_plugins` table that have been long removed via the Craft CP panel, and removed from the composer files also.

However when I enable project config, these deleted plugins appear in the plugins section of the yaml file with their status set to 1, which - I think maybe - prevents it being applied to other environments.

Is the best thing to do just manually delete the old plugins from the db? Or is there a 'proper' way to clean them up/out?

(Project is running Craft 3.1.34)

Comment: I tried both ways ( by using composer and by manually from CP) *_plugins table is updated whenever a plugin added or removed.

Comment: So how you removed the plugin?